# What does this shortcode do?

Tags: shortcode

```
function my_shortcode($atts, $content = null){

    extract(shortcode_atts(array("type" => "warrning"), $atts));
    return ".$content.";
}
add_shortcode("warrning_dialog", "my_shortcode");
```

I know that it creates shortcode [warrning_dialog], but what i don't understand are extract() function and return ".$content."

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty, it doesn't do very much. If the code is literally as you describe, all it does is add fullstops either side of the content. If that's not what happens then there's likely missing code.

As for the other parts:

#### What is `extract`?

`extract` is a PHP function used in a lot of older WP code examples, and it's very bad practice. It takes the keys and values in an array, and turns them into variables.

The problem is that you don't know for sure what's inside the the array and what variables it will create. `extract` can cause problems by overwritting other variables. It's also impossiblet for editors and tooling to detect bugs like this when using `extract`, and will generate false warnings.

`extract` also encourages poorly written code. By relying on variables created this way, you face problems if those values were never in the array to begin with, generating notices. Always avoid `extract`, it was a mistake of the authors to use it. It is not good practice.

In the example in your question, the `extract` call isn't even used, and the result can be  simplified to:

```php
function my_shortcode($atts, $content = ''){
    return ".$content.";
}
add_shortcode("warrning_dialog", "my_shortcode");
```

#### What About `shortcode_atts`?

`extract` expects an array of keys and values, that it turns into variables and values, so where is this array coming from?

It comes from `$atts` the attributes passed to the shortcode, e.g. `[shortcode att1="value" another_attribute="anothervalue"]content[/shortcode]`

But what if the user doesn't specify an attribute we need? Well, `shortcode_atts` lets us take the attribute list, and add the default values if they're missing. This way they're always there:

```php
shortcode_atts(array("type" => "warrning"), $atts)
```

This would be better written as:

```php
$atts = shortcode_atts( [
    'type' => 'warrning'
], $atts);
```

If we needed to access the attribute type, we could use `$atts['type']`

#### What About `".$content."`?

This is just a string with a variable embedded in it. For example:

```php
$name = 'Tom';
echo "My name is $name";
```

The above code will output:

> My name is Tom

It's also a great way to introduce security issues to your site. This is because it's not possible to late escape/sanitise this way. Always use concatenation instead.

`".$content."` is the same as `'.'.$content.'.'`